# Why does Thorin leave Bilbo when the key hole is not found?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit, the-desolation-of-smaug

In [The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit:_The_Desolation_of_Smaug) when the key hole is not found on the Lonely Mountain, why do Thorin and all the dwarfs get disappointed so quickly and leave Bilbo, while Bilbo remains positive?

This was the dwarfs' fight not Bilbo's, still he believed that there will be a way. This scene was really disappointing for me, because they worked with so much dedication and all the trouble they have gone through just to loose hope so quickly. Kindly help me understand this situation.

Answer (score 3):

They only had a brief window of time in which they had to operate, the last light of Durin's day. When the sun set, they thought their only opportunity was gone. Bilbo wasn't limited in thinking about the small window of time like the others, so he kept at it, and eventually realized the last light of Durin's day was the moonlight.

Comment: In my opinion this situation elaborate dwarfs' characteristics more deeply, that they are the most impatient beings of Middle-Earth.

Comment: And if the Dwarfs didn't realize why they had brought the "Thief" along at this point, they surely did after.

Comment: I found this plot device, while stretching things a bit, to be a great illustration of how different people think differently.  The more diverse the group, the more likely a solution will be found.